# What is Google publisher key ,where it is in google console

Tags: android

Trying android license service,here i am not getting what is key from [google publisher console](http://blog.csdn.net/booboo2k/article/details/7525463)
when it is created.how to see it.

Answer (score 0):

@Prabha: It's actually ***your*** base64-encoded RSA public key used for publishing your apps. You publish your apps in Google Developer Console using this key. Go [here](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=androiddeveloper&passive=true&nui=1&continue=https://play.google.com/apps/publish&followup=https://play.google.com/apps/publish) to log in to Developer Console. If you don't have an account yet, create one for yourself. *(Note: You may need to pay a developer's fee to Google before you can use Google Developer Console. Also, go [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622?hl=en&ref_topic=2897388) to see how much Google will charge you for each purchase made by your customers.)*

The publisher key is found in **Developer Console** (once you've logged in) under **Services & APIs** menu option. *Note: Google now allows separate public keys for each of your apps. Previously, you were only allowed to have one public key for all your apps.*

Also, check this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) on how to create licencing for your app.

**IMPORTANT:** You may also want to google "lucky patcher". It's an app that has been around for a while now that can be used to circumvent Google's licencing module. Having said that, also google for coding techniques used to counteract "lucky patcher" or any other apps used for hacking.

Last but not least, you may also want to consider setting up your own servers to do your own licencing validation on top of Google's licencing requirements to counter piracy.

Oh, one more thing, doing all this will make your app harder to crack or hack but not entirely impossible! Keep that in mind when you build techniques to safeguard your apps against piracy...

Answer (score 0):

In all reality, it doesn't matter what measures you take. Though it is always good that you take them for safe measures. However, more advanced 'modders/hackers' don't tend to break down an app and its files more in less. Unless it is more involved with theming. No, in fact, the more prefered method would be reverse engineering/debugging. A tool for such a thing would be like IDA - check it out. Even though you could use this very same software to exploit the weaknesses so that you may make the necessary patches as needed in your apk this same tool can be used to see how everything forms as a unity this breaking it apart and redirecting its input so come time for installation of the apk it simply reads off the info as 'true' vice 'false'. This method is known as 'in game hack'. This is also how keys or licenses are bypassed. Its not that the key or license is removed, but that the input/output commands are being redirecting around the key so as if to camouflage it. Picture a window with four glasses. Each square glass represents something significant towards the operation of the apk. With that square gives values, truths, false, etc and based upon the answer will determine if it is directed by a green, yellow, red, or blue arrow which leads to its own specific square glass in the window according to its color. Now with making adjustments one could change some paths and completely go around one of those square glass and still maintain the apps full potential. :-). In other words - do your research. You got some learning to do.

Comment: Agreed, the OP will need to put in some research effort. I see many Android developers in the past made the mistake of just checking true/false from server validation - which can be easily circumvented. Nowadays, many modern relational databases offer encryption methods e.g. You have `aes_encrypt` and `aes_decrypt` in MySQL that you can use to your advantage. It's one way of making it harder to circumvent your app's security and licencing...